# Can't Store More Than One FormItems Data To DB

Tags: html, database, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7.*`.

I have a `form` and it's `formItems`, Like `form HasMany formItems` and `formItems belongsTo form`, when i hit submit, i see in `DB` only one `formItems` is stored, although i try to store more than one `formitem`.

**Here is my `store method`:**

```js
public function store(Request $request) {
  $formItems = collect();
  // dd($request);
  // dd($request->formItems);
  // // dd($familymember);
  foreach($request['formItems'] as $formItem) {
    $formItems->push(new FormItem([
      'family_name' => $formItem['family_name'],
      'family_phone' => $formItem['family_phone'],

    ]));
  }

  $form = Form::create([
    'user_phone' => $request['user_phone'],
    'user_cnic' => $request['user_cnic'],
  ]);

  $form->formItems()->saveMany($formItems);
}
```

**Here is my HTML for `formItems`:**

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <table class="table table-bordered fieldGroup">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="formItems[0][family_name]" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Full Name"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="formItems[0][family_phone]" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Phone"></td>
          <td colspan="3">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>+</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<fieldset form="formId">
  <table class="table table-bordered fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="formItems[0][family_name]" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Full Name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="formItems[0][family_phone]" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Phone"></td>
        <td><a style="align-items: center; justify-content: center; display: flex;" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>x</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

**`From` Model:**

```js
class Form extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_phone',
        'user_cnic',
    ];

    protected $with = [
        'formItems',
    ];

    public function formItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FormItem::class);
    }
}
```

**`FromItem` Model:**

```js
class FormItem extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'form_id',
        'family_name',
        'family_phone',
    ];

    public function form()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Form::class);
    }
}
```

**Updated Image:**
[image]

**`dd($request->all())` result:**

```js
array:12 [▼
  "_token" => "tEDC2rrDXInWeKQzFFSyk0gRoiC19Dr4HIqpf5P1"
  "user_phone" => null
  "user_cnic" => null
  "user_dob" => null
  "user_gender" => "male"
  "user_landmark" => null
  "user_hfname" => null
  "user_address" => null
  "user_name" => null
  "user_family_no" => "1"
  "user_email" => null
  "formItems" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "family_relation" => "father"
      "family_name" => null
      "family_dob" => null
      "family_hfname" => null
      "family_phone" => null
      "family_email" => null
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below code

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $form = Form::create([
        'user_phone' => $request['user_phone'],
        'user_cnic' => $request['user_cnic'],
    ]);

    $form_items = [];
    foreach($request['formItems'] as $form_item) {
        $form_items[] = new FormItem([
          'form_id' => $form->id,
          'family_name' => $form_item['family_name'],
          'family_phone' => $form_item['family_phone']
        ]);
    }

    $form->formItems()->saveMany($form_items);
}
```

Comment: It's giving me the same result, it store only the last form_items record in  DB..... see updated image for better understanding....

Comment: Please give some explanation why your code might solve the problem, such that others can learn from it

Comment: dd(request()->all()) in your controller returns only one formItem in the array. thats why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have duplicated the inputs names:

```
name="formItems[0][family_name]"
name="formItems[0][family_phone]"
```

You always have this name, and I guess it should be one number up each new item. example:

```
name="formItems[0][family_name]"
name="formItems[0][family_phone]"
name="formItems[1][family_name]"
name="formItems[1][family_phone]"
```

Comment: I have 2 formItems forms, one that is displaying on frontend, other is its clone, which i added dynamically using jQuery, i did this in original form `name="formItems[0][family_name]"` and did this in clone form `name="formItems[1][family_name]"`, now when i submit form 2 formItems stored in `DB`. may be there is a problem in my form, but don't know hot to resolve this. @nyu.exe

Comment: Maybe input should be inside `<form>` tag? What does `dd(request()->all())` in your controller returns?

Comment: As you can see it only recieves one formItem in the array, thats why it only stores one. I guess the error is in the form...

Try adding this HTML attribute to your dinamic inputs: `form="YOURFORMID"`

examples: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form.asp

Comment: No it was not an error my error is resolved.... Thanks for supporting me bro. @nyu.exe

Comment: Its fine then! :)